# ¿Cómo puedo utilizar correctamente las funciones asíncronas en Vala?

Tags: hilos, gtk, vala

No logro solventar el problema de procesar por separado código que se ejecutarían al cerrar la ventana.   Este es mi código:

```
this.delete_event.connect (() => {
    var loop = new MainLoop ();

    proceso.begin (int valores, (obj, res) => {
        try {
            loop.quit ();
            Gtk.main_quit ();
        } catch (ThreadError e) {
            stderr.printf("ERROR: %s\n", e.message);
        }
    });

    loop.run ();
    return false;
});



public async int proceso (int valores) throws ThreadError {
    SourceFunc proceso_callback = proceso.callback;

    ThreadFunc<void*> run = () => {
        /*
         * Acá va todo el código que quiero que se ejecute
         * Son cientos de instrucciones que hace que se cuelque al cerrar la aplicación
         */

        Idle.add((owned) proceso_callback);
        Thread.exit (1.to_pointer ());
        return null;
    };
    Thread<void*> proceso_thread = new Thread<void*> ("proceso_thread", run);

    yield;
    return 1;
}
```

Estoy utilizando dicha función porque al momento de cerrar de la manera tradicional (sin usar threads ni nada por el estilo) la ventana tarda una barbaridad en cerrar debido a que son cientos de valores los que tiene que guardar. Por eso estoy buscando una alternativo para que esto pase desapercibido. ¿Alguna idea?

Comment: ¿Que tipo de valores quieres guardar? Podrias utilizar [GSettings](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/GSettingsSample)¿Son Threads(hilos) o Métodos Asíncronos? son términos diferentes

Comment: Justamentes estaba usando eso. Yo quiero guardar los valores en un archivo app.gschema.xml, pero igual tarda mucho en cerrar la aplicación.

Comment: Si guardo pocos valores, por ejemplo 10, al archivo la aplicación cierra normalmente, en cambio como tengo la necesidad de guardar casi 100 es cuendo se traba.

Answer (score 1):

```
private static int main (string[] args) {
  Gtk.init(ref args);

  var win = new Gtk.Window();
  win.show();
  win.destroy.connect((w) => {
      w.hide();

      GLib.Idle.add(() => {
          /* ...  */

          Gtk.main_quit();
          return false;
        });
    });

  Gtk.main();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: En la compilación me arroja que el método "hide" no existe para el objeto w. Y también busqué en la documentación de Vala y no se encuentra más dicho método,

Comment: [Gtk.Widget.hide()](https://valadoc.org/gtk+-3.0/Gtk.Widget.hide.html) / [gtk_widget_hide()](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-hide). Esto funciona para mi. ¿Intentó el código exacto que publiqué?

Comment: Si, intenté y funciona. Ahora que veo el problema son los datos a guardar. inclusive hago mensajes por consola para determinar en qué parte se traba pero se ejecutan inclusive mucho antes de los datos a guardar. Los datos se guardan en un archivo XML y aunque pongo los mensajes para debuggear al final se me ejecutan primero y el guardado de datos se ejecuta luego.

Comment: No digo que está mal tu solución, funciona, pero como tengo que guardar datos en un XML  puede que tarde por eso

Comment: Lo que publique debería permitirle realizar una operación de larga ejecución luego de que la ventana se haya cerrado; Si tiene problemas con otra cosa, esa es una pregunta diferente, por lo que debe crear una nueva pregunta (e incluir un [MCVE] (https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).